# Can't log in with stolen bank accounts

Tags: uplink

I just accepted a ton of  "our esteemed colleague wishes to make a donation" missions where I have to steal a bank account and make a money transfer to another account.

How can I perform these missions?

Comment: For a minute there, the question title threw me off.... +1 for a truly "eye-catching" title

Comment: *slowclap* This is definitely one of the most awesomely titled questions I have seen here.

Comment: I'm guessing this sarcasm?

Comment: No, we have a [long and proud tradition of questions whose titles are absurd without context](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196/3936)

Answer (score 8):

There is a website dedicated to walkthrough each kind of mission, including the minimum requirement for them.
Here is the link for that specific mission  [Our Esteemed colleague wishes to make a donation](http://guide.modlink.net/section3.php#12) 
How to complete "Our esteemed colleague wishes to make a donation".

#### The Setup

1. Bypass the Monitor if you can - Level 5
2. Bypass/Disable the Firewall - Level 5
3. Bypass/Disable the Proxy - Level 5
4. Enter the account number you were given as the User Name
5. Use the password cracker on the password field

#### The Heist

1. Transfer the money to the indicated account.
2. **Reply to the mission email now.**

#### Clearing Your Tracks

1. Delete the transfer logs.
   *It is important that you reply to the mission email before you do this step.  Otherwise the client cannot confirm that the job was done.*
2. Delete the statements.
3. Disconnect and clear your bounce trail.

Comment: Extra info - for a complete bank heist statements need to be deleted from both sides of the transaction. And, if you've opened accounts in every bank (as should everyone), it is possible for one of those missions to target your account. It is than neccessary to take care of the other side or bad things might happen.